# python multiprocessing map function

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

I encountered a problem while writing the python code with a multiprocessing map function. The minimum code to reproduce the problem is like

```
import multiprocessing as mp

if __name__ == '__main__':

    def f(x):
        return x*x

    num_workers = 2
    with mp.Pool(num_workers) as p:
        print(p.map(f, [1,2,3]))
```

If one runs this piece of code, I got the error message

```
AttributeError: Can't get attribute 'f' on <module '__mp_main__' from 'main.py'>
```

However, If I move f-function outside the main function, i.e.

```
import multiprocessing as mp

def f(x):
    return x*x

if __name__ == '__main__':

    num_workers = 2
    with mp.Pool(num_workers) as p:
        print(p.map(f, [1,2,3]))
```

It works this time. I am wondering what's the difference between them and how can I get an error in the first version. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What are you talking about? The first code runs without any problems. See https://ideone.com/qLGWzR
Please try out any code snippet before you post a question. This is not the first time today you posted a question with claims about your code that are just not true.

Comment: @Jakube Doesn't work for me as well, using plain old pycharm, no idea why it works on an online IDE..

Comment: Do you have any different indentations? Tabs instead of spaces, or so?
And what Python version are you running it with?
Afaik the code snippet is perfectly fine, and runs without any problems also locally for me.

Comment: @Jakube I tested again, It doesn't work on my mac computer. Python version is 3.9.7 :)

Comment: @Jakube I can reproduce OP's error on an m1 mac (python 3.9.5). This is not a false report.

Comment: I'm not sure how processes work on M1 chips.
But this sound's like a bug in Python itself. Best to raise an issue on their Github page: https://github.com/python/cpython/issues

Comment: This will happen on systems that spawn rather than fork sub-processes. This has nothing to do with the chipset

Comment: @Jakube This is **not** a bug

Comment: The [programming guidelines](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#programming-guidelines) are pretty clear about that. The forked processes import the module and run the function. If the function is defined inside the main guard, then he new processes can't access it. You only need to protect the ***entry point*** i.e. the line `p.map(f, [1,2,3])`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on your operating system, sub-processes will either be forked or spawned. macOS, for example, will spawn whereas Windows will fork.

You can enforce forking but you need to fully understand the implications of doing so.

For this specific question a workaround could be implemented thus:

```
import multiprocessing as mp
from multiprocessing import set_start_method

if __name__ == '__main__':
    def f(x):
        return x*x
    set_start_method('fork')
    num_workers = 2
    with mp.Pool(num_workers) as p:
        print(p.map(f, [1,2,3]))
```

Answer (score 2):

This will vary between operating systems, but the basic reason is that this line of code

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
```

is telling the Python interpreter to only include anything in this code section in the main process when run as a script - it won't be included in any sub process, nor will it appear if you import it as a module. So when you do this

```
import multiprocessing as mp

if __name__ == '__main__':

    def f(x):
        return x*x

    num_workers = 2
    with mp.Pool(num_workers) as p:
        print(p.map(f, [1,2,3]))
```

any sub processes created by p.map will not have the definition of function f